# Angular 2 services - data cleared out whenever I change routes?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have an angular 2 single page application and everything is rendered from one  or component specific templates on the same page yet when I use this.router.navigate or a routerLink on the navbar to get around my app, every time it clears out the data I have stored in my services, specifically an array of JSON objects, and it renders the one component again and does its ngOnInit which checks whether there is data in the service and because there isn't it pulls the data again from the database. I would like this data to persist so the client is not hitting my server every 2 seconds for the same data, how do I achieve this without using localStorage? Would lazy loading do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the service in `@NgModule(...) export class AppModule()` or a module imported to `AppModule` for it to become global and have the same lifetime as the application.

If you provide a service in a component, then the lifetime of the service ends with the lifetime of the component.

Comment: Do you mean like this? because I have it already:
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...stuff
  ],
  imports: [... stuff
  ],
  providers: [EventService, AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: That's what I mean. This way nothing will be cleared. Are you providing `EventService` or `AutService` in a `@Component({providers: [...]}` as well?

Comment: no just in the main app.module.ts and then importing the service and injecting it into my @component's constructor:  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

Comment: Then I guess it's some code of yours that clears the value. I doubt Angular itself is doing anything like that. Perhaps you can reproduce in a Plunker

Answer (score -2):

Try using a Singleton shared service. Then use the getter, setter methods to access data

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedStoreService {
    static instance: SharedStoreService;
    private jsonArray:any =[];

    constructor(){
       return SharedStoreService.instance = SharedStoreService.instance || this;
    }

    setJsonArray(list){
       this.jsonArray = list;
    } 
    getJsonArray(){
       return this.jsonArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you implementing your custom "singleton" pattern when Angular provides that out of the box?

Comment: instead of using the static key-word, just use the service as a regular angular 2 service. Access the variables using the getters and setters after injecting the service in your components.

Comment: I already use it as a service injected into my components but I set it directly in the component when the http subscribe returns the data like this.eventService.eventsArray = this.events from within my component. Is that the problem? Is it pointing to the array in my component which goes out of scope on changing routes?

Comment: I tried this in my component which imports my service         this.eventService.fetchData().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.eventService.setEvents(data); but the array is still getting cleared every time I use a route.